# When I increase or decrease the volume a headphones symbol appears on my iPhone 6

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone, headphones

On my iPhone 6 I see a headphones symbol that only appears when I increase or decrease the volume. I have no headphones plugged in.

Maybe related, I am also unable to get a sound notification, and for all calls I can’t hear the voice. I don't use a Bluetooth headset and I've never changed any settings.

I've had this iPhone for just one week. Is this a hardware or software problem? If software, how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Always a good place to start is to shutdown and reboot your iPhone. If that doesn't work then it's time to investigate further.

If a reboot has no effect, is it possible that your iPhone is connecting to some sort of Bluetooth device? It may not necessarily be a headset (I know you said you don't use one) - it could be a speaker, a receiver, headphones, etc.

The next time this happens, the first thing I would do is go to Bluetooth settings at Settings > Bluetooth and check to see if any devices are listed there? If you see anything you don't recognise or ever want connected, tap on the blue ⓘ symbol on the right of it and select Forget This Device.

Another troubleshooting step you can take is to disable Bluetooth altogether for a while to see what difference, if any, that makes. Once again, you can do this at: Settings > Bluetooth.

If none of this helps, you could check your headphone socket to make sure it's clear of any debris. You can also plug some headphones in and see how your iPhone behaves and then unplug them again.

Finally, you do have various Reset options available to you at Settings > General > Reset. You could start with the Reset Network Settings option (note this will reset Wi-Fi networks and passwords, mobile network settings, VPNs, etc.).

Otherwise you could do a full backup of your iPhone and then do a full reset of all content and settings (also available at Settings > General > Reset). This erases everything, so make sure you've done a full backup so you have something to restore from!

Comment: I disabled Bluetooth. I did reset erase all. Many time shut down and restart. I did not use any Bluetooth device. My mobile I buy newly. No dust inside headphone socket. I plugged headphones and removed. The problem come back again same.

Comment: In that case I recommend you contact Apple, as it'll be the quickest way you'll get a solution - especially since it could very well be a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for ur responding. Finally when I updated iOS 11.1 my problem was resolved. Now my mobile work properly.

Answer (score 1):

please try these things. Your volume mode set to Headphone. So you can't hear voice from someone and won't sound any music.

1. Plug & Unplug headphones.
2. Reset your iPhone. **Settings**->**General**->**Reset All Settings**
3. Turn off & turn on your iPhone
4. Clean your Headphone Jack input (ex: using pen or something like that)

Comment: I did same as u said but same problem come back.